# SQLite UPDATE query does not run

Tags: android, sqlite

I don't know why, but this code doesn't work (but runs without exception):

```java
try {
    db.rawQuery(UPDATE_ALL_REMINDERS_AND_SET_METHOD_NONE, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();            
}
```

UPDATE_ALL_REMINDERS_AND_SET_METHOD_NONE is:

```
UPDATE dn_reminders SET method = 0
```

All field and table names are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `execSQL()` for SQL that updates the database.

`rawQuery()` alone just compiles the SQL but does not run it.

Comment: Then there's another problem not shown here. For example, wrapping database updates in a transaction that gets rolled back. Or you're just examining a wrong version of the database file.